# Calculate $\lim_{z\to \infty}\frac{\cos(i+z)-1}{(z+i)^4}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

> Calculate  $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to \infty}\frac{\cos(i+z)-1}{(z+i)^4}$

I'm pretty sure it's equal to $0$, but I find it difficult to show it formally.

Comment: Hint: $\cos(iy) = \cosh(y)$

Comment: "I am pretty sure it's equal to $0$". And why is that? If $z$ is of complex nature, the cosine no longer is bounded

Comment: @gammatester this hint make my think it's not converting. assume we want to calculate $\lim_{z\to \infty}\frac{cos(z)-1}{(z)^4}$. if we set $z=iy$ , $y\in R$ then $cosh(y)-1$ seems to overcome $(iy)^4$. on the other hand if choose $z_m=2\pi m$, $m \in Z$, then i get zero.

Comment: @imranfat ,please see my last comment, am I wrong?

Comment: I tend to believe that this limit does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $z\to\infty$, then also $z+i\to\infty$ and conversely. So your limit is the same as
$$
\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{\cos z-1}{z^4}
$$
Now
$$
\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}
$$
For real $z$, the limit is $0$. For $z=it$, $t>0$, the limit is
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{e^{-t}+e^{t}}{t^4}=\infty
$$